# AS3 bug on resizing after rotation?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

```
trace( "before" );
trace( this.height );
trace( this.width );
trace( this.rotation );

this.height += 30;
this.width += 30;

trace( "after" );
trace( this.height );
trace( this.width );
trace( this.rotation );
```

The object is a 100 px sided square rotated by 90 or -90 degrees so the rotation should never even make a difference.
But what I get in those traces is:

```
before
100
100
-90
after
160
100
-90
```

Does anyone know why this happens? I "fixed" it by setting the rotation to 0 and then back to whatever it was but I don't think this should be required for such simple operations.

Comment: You mean the problem is that the `width` is  not `160` pixels too?

Comment: I should have made it clearer, sorry about that. They should both be 130 after resizing. Instead, for some reason, the height ends up being 160 while the width remains at 100.